Selected item in sub UILIT is not displayed as active
I created a script that uses handlers to acquire keyframes of the active object's F-curves in real-time. The script works without any issues, but for some reason, the active index of the sublist (keyframe list) always resets to 0, causing the selection state to always be at 0.
Clicking works, so the information is being correctly updated for the intended keyframe. However, when I turn off the handler, the display returns to normal. Therefore, it seems that the active index resets during the re-creation of the keyframe list.
How can I avoid this issue? Is there a good method to resolve it?

import bpy

# キーフレームプロパティグループ
class KeyframePropertyGroup(bpy.types.PropertyGroup):
    frame: bpy.props.IntProperty(name="Frame")
    value: bpy.props.FloatProperty(name="Value")

class FCurvePropertyGroup(bpy.types.PropertyGroup):
    name: bpy.props.StringProperty(name="Name")  # 追加したプロパティ
    fcurve_path: bpy.props.StringProperty(name="F-Curve Path")
    keyframes: bpy.props.CollectionProperty(type=KeyframePropertyGroup)
    active_keyframe_index: bpy.props.IntProperty(
        update=lambda self, context: jump_to_keyframe(self, context)
    )

class TargetObjectPropertyGroup(bpy.types.PropertyGroup):
    object: bpy.props.PointerProperty(
        name="Target Object",
        type=bpy.types.Object,
        description="Target object to get F-Curve paths from"
    )
    fcurves: bpy.props.CollectionProperty(type=FCurvePropertyGroup)
    active_fcurve_index: bpy.props.IntProperty()

class MyProperties(bpy.types.PropertyGroup):
    active_fcurves: bpy.props.CollectionProperty(type=FCurvePropertyGroup)
    target_objects: bpy.props.CollectionProperty(type=TargetObjectPropertyGroup)
    active_fcurve_index: bpy.props.IntProperty()
    active_target_index: bpy.props.IntProperty()

    def update_active_fcurves(self, context):
#        print("###",self.target_objects)
        self.active_fcurves.clear()
        obj = context.active_object
        if obj and obj.animation_data:
            for fcurve in obj.animation_data.action.fcurves:
                item = self.active_fcurves.add()
                item.name = fcurve.data_path  # nameプロパティにfcurveのデータパスを設定
                item.fcurve_path = fcurve.data_path
                item.keyframes.clear()
                for kp in fcurve.keyframe_points:
                    kf_item = item.keyframes.add()
                    kf_item.frame = int(kp.co[0])
                    kf_item.value = kp.co[1]

    def update_target_fcurves(self, context):
        for target in self.target_objects:
            target.fcurves.clear()
            obj = target.object
            if obj and obj.animation_data:
                for fcurve in obj.animation_data.action.fcurves:
                    item = target.fcurves.add()
                    item.name = fcurve.data_path  # nameプロパティにfcurveのデータパスを設定
                    item.fcurve_path = fcurve.data_path
                    item.keyframes.clear()
                    for kp in fcurve.keyframe_points:
                        kf_item = item.keyframes.add()
                        kf_item.frame = int(kp.co[0])
                        kf_item.value = kp.co[1]

def jump_to_keyframe(self, context):
    if self.active_keyframe_index >= 0 and self.active_keyframe_index < len(self.keyframes):
        keyframe = self.keyframes[self.active_keyframe_index]
        context.scene.frame_set(keyframe.frame)

# カスタムUIリストの定義
class OBJECT_UL_FCurveList(bpy.types.UIList):
    def draw_item(self, context, layout, data, item, icon, active_data, active_propname, index):
        layout.label(text=item.name)  # nameプロパティを表示

class OBJECT_UL_KeyframeList(bpy.types.UIList):
    def draw_item(self, context, layout, data, item, icon, active_data, active_propname, index):
        mark = "*" if item.frame == context.scene.frame_current else ""
        layout.label(text=f"{mark} {item.frame}:  {item.value}")

# パネルクラスの定義
class OBJECT_PT_FCurvePathsPanel(bpy.types.Panel):
    bl_label = "F-Curve Paths"
    bl_idname = "OBJECT_PT_fcurve_paths_panel"
    bl_space_type = 'VIEW_3D'
    bl_region_type = 'UI'
    bl_category = 'Tool'

    @classmethod
    def poll(cls, context):
        return context.active_object is not None

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        scene = context.scene
        props = scene.my_props
        current_frame = scene.frame_current  # 現在のフレームを取得
        layout.operator("object.add_target_object", text="Add Target Object")

        row = layout.row()
        col1 = row.column()
        col2 = row.column()

        col1.label(text="Active Object F-Curves:")
        col1.template_list(
            "OBJECT_UL_FCurveList",
            "active_fcurves",
            props,
            "active_fcurves",
            props,
            "active_fcurve_index"
        )

        # アクティブオブジェクトのキーフレーム一覧
        col1.label(text="Active Object Keyframes:")
        if props.active_fcurve_index >= 0 and props.active_fcurve_index < len(props.active_fcurves):
            active_fcurve = props.active_fcurves[props.active_fcurve_index]
            col1.template_list(
                "OBJECT_UL_KeyframeList",
                "keyframes",
                active_fcurve,
                "keyframes",
                active_fcurve,
                "active_keyframe_index"
            )

        for i, target in enumerate(props.target_objects):
            box = col2.box()
            box.operator("object.remove_target_object", text="Remove Target Object").index = i
            box.prop(target, "object")
            box.template_list(
                "OBJECT_UL_FCurveList",
                f"target_fcurves_{i}",
                target,
                "fcurves",
                target,
                "active_fcurve_index"
            )

            target_obj = target.object
            if target.active_fcurve_index >= 0 and target.active_fcurve_index < len(target.fcurves):
                target_fcurve = target.fcurves[target.active_fcurve_index]
                box.template_list(
                    "OBJECT_UL_KeyframeList",
                    f"keyframes_{i}",
                    target_fcurve,
                    "keyframes",
                    target_fcurve,
                    "active_keyframe_index"
                )
  
            col2 = row.column()

# ターゲットオブジェクトを追加するオペレーター
class OBJECT_OT_AddTargetObject(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "object.add_target_object"
    bl_label = "Add Target Object"

    def execute(self, context):
        props = context.scene.my_props
        target = props.target_objects.add()
        target.object = None
        return {'FINISHED'}

# ターゲットオブジェクトを削除するオペレーター
class OBJECT_OT_RemoveTargetObject(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "object.remove_target_object"
    bl_label = "Remove Target Object"
    index: bpy.props.IntProperty()

    def execute(self, context):
        props = context.scene.my_props
        if len(props.target_objects) > self.index:
            props.target_objects.remove(self.index)
        return {'FINISHED'}

# クラスの登録
classes = [
    KeyframePropertyGroup,
    FCurvePropertyGroup,
    TargetObjectPropertyGroup,
    MyProperties,
    OBJECT_UL_FCurveList,
    OBJECT_UL_KeyframeList,
    OBJECT_PT_FCurvePathsPanel,
    OBJECT_OT_AddTargetObject,
    OBJECT_OT_RemoveTargetObject,
]

def register():
    for cls in classes:
        bpy.utils.register_class(cls)
    bpy.types.Scene.my_props = bpy.props.PointerProperty(type=MyProperties)
    bpy.app.handlers.depsgraph_update_post.append(update_fcurves_handler)

def unregister():
    bpy.app.handlers.depsgraph_update_post.remove(update_fcurves_handler)
    for cls in classes:
        bpy.utils.unregister_class(cls)
    del bpy.types.Scene.my_props


def update_fcurves_handler(scene):
    
    scene.my_props.update_active_fcurves(bpy.context)
    scene.my_props.update_target_fcurves(bpy.context)
    

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()

